# Image change with every sentence said in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I want my image view to change with every sentence in str, but it doesn't change

```
let elements = ["1","2","3"]
var cx = 0
for str in components{
  OutImage.image = UIImage(named: elements1[cx+1])
  myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
  myUtterance.rate = 0.4
  myUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.3
  myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
  myUtterance.voice = voiceToUse
  synth.speak(myUtterance)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a for loop, because `speak` is asynchronous, meaning that it will execute in "parallel" with the rest of your code. By the time your for loop finishes, the speech synthesiser probably didn't even start synthesising your first sentence!

The solution, is to use an `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`. In particular, you need to implement this method:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, 
                  didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
```

This delegate method is called when the synthesiser finishes an utterance.

In the method, you can figure out which image should be shown by looking at the `cx` variable. Then you should increment `cx`. After that, using `cx`, get the next utterance to be spoken and call `speak`. You should also remember to check for whether `cx` is the end of the array!